# Почему моё python приложение запускается спустя 1-3 секунды?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске уже скомпилированного файла (.exe) открывается консоль и только спустя 1-3 секунды программа начинает выполнять код. При компиляции есть варнинги, может ли это быть из за них?

Проверено не только у меня.
Исходный код см. ниже:

```
from steam import SteamID

id = input("Insert link (For Example: https://steamcommunity.com/id/gaben): ")
steamid = SteamID.from_url(id)
if steamid is None:
    print ("Error: Link is not valid =(")
else:
    print("Permanent link his user: "+ str(steamid))
```

Comment: Что-то изменилось?)

Comment: Отступы. В том виде как было отступы были некорректными, программа бы не запустилась.

Comment: Программа запустилась, это я наверное так скопировал. Проблема не в этом, программа работает. Проблема в том, что она начинает работать спустя 1-3 секунды после запуска.

Comment: Вы спросили, что изменилось, я ответил.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы скомпилировали в `exe` через `PyInstaller`, при этом всё в один файл, то это оправдано. "Под капотом" загрузчик PyInstaller сначала всё распаковывает (напр., все требующиеся библиотеки) во временную папку, и только затем уже запускает саму программу.

Кроме того, PyInstaller пакует все библиотеки, которые у вас в данный момент были установлены (даже если вы не используете их в своей программе), а это увеличивает время для распаковки. Здесь хорошей идеей будет использовать виртуальное окружение, и установить все библиотеки в него. Если вы используете только стандартную библиотеку Python, то кроме `PyInstaller` вам больше ничего не потребуется.

Comment: Я использую дополнительную библиотеку `steam` для получения `steamid`, больше у меня нет никаких установленных библиотек. Да, скомпилировал через `PyInstaller` в один `exe` файл. Есть адекватная альтернатива `PyInstaller` где такой проблемы нету? Потому-что через виртуальное окружение кажется не совсем удобно, если я буду отдавать свою программу другим, если я правильно всё понял, прочитая документацию..

Comment: И кстати, мое приложение весит 15мб.. Хотя кода в нем совсем мало. При компиляции не в один файл в папке много не нужного, с чем это связано? Скрин: https://imgur.com/a/5AQEoVZ

Comment: @antondreamer Виртуальное окружение нужно для того, чтобы вы её скомпилировали только с нужными библиотеками. Программу в `exe` можно и без "окружения" отдавать.

Comment: @antondreamer Если вы компилируйте не в один файл, то в папку копируется всё нужное (почти, кое-что можно удалить) для запуска программы, в том числе и библиотеки.

Comment: Вообще, я вижу `steam` при установке много зависимостей тянет за собой, из-за этого по итогу один файл и весит 15 метров, и поэтому долго запускается.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу скомпилировать только с нужными библиотеками в `exe`?

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема.
Оказалось, что это встроенный антивирус Windows долго проверяет файл .exe при запуске.
После отключения защиты в реальном времени время запуска значительно уменьшается.